# If I reopen my google play dev account, will my apps get back?

Tags: android, google-play

I forgot to pay Developers fee for Google Play. And now it seems they're unreachable. Will they get back when I make my payment?

Comment: Are you sure that the deactivation of your account related to the developer fee? As long as I know the fee is just for one time and needed to be pay at the beginning. Your app may be violated any of market rules or license agreements, but in this case, you should receive respective notification.

Comment: @SelimOk the sad thing is I didnt received any notification as far as i know. Is there a place that you know I can check this?

Comment: In the regular case you have to receive all announcements and notifications directly to your email address used by the account registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out because of the Coppa change, you have to enter that is your app should be avaible for kids under age 13.

https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/complying-coppa-frequently-asked-questions#Web